# Highlight repetitions

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I have a column in Excel and want to find and paint values which are repeated three times. I know it can be achieved with Conditional Formatting but I don't know what I should write in the formula space.

Edit:
For example 
the column is

```
3
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
7
8
8
8
```

There is only '5' and '8' which is repeated 3 times. If I want to paint values repeated 3 times, 5 and 8 values should be painted.

I think I should use conditional formatting > highlight cell rules > more rules > Use a formula to determine which cells to format. And I also know that I should use COUNTIF formula there. But how?

Comment: An example of what you are trying to achieve will help.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight your range (in my example, `A1:A12`), and use this formula:

`=countif($A$1:$A$12,$A1)>=3`

Then choose whatever format/fill you want and it should be good to go.  Note that you must use the absolute cell references in the first part of the formula, or else it won't work properly.

Here's a gif:

[image]
Note that I had to edit the formula after entering it. For some reason, Excel changes my `$A1` criteria to `$A123091` (or whever the last cell in col. A is). So just edit the formula and it should work.

Edit2: Okay, as @pnuts pointed out, the reason you have to edit the formula is because I started my range selection at the bottom.  If you start in A1, and drag down, you can enter the formula as I have it above and it'll work immediately. No tweak necessary.

Comment: I still cannot do it.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you expand a little? I'll edit my OP with a .gif.

Comment: @OğuzSarıalioğlu - Does this solve the problem? If so, would you mind marking as the answer? If not, please let me know what's not working and we can get to the bottom of it!